# Group multiple records as one records and assign values in python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe in `python`. the columns of the data frame are `Id`, `loc_time`, `loc_number`, `status`.

the data is below:

```
Id  loc_time    loc_number  status
1   01:25.5     1105        testing on
2   02:25.9     1105        testing off
3   03:28.5     1105        testing off
4   04:25.5     1105        testing off
5   05:25.9     1105        testing on
6   06:25.5     1105        testing on
7   07:25.9     1105        testing off
8   08:25.6     1105        testing off
9   09:25.9     1106        testing on
10  10:25.6     1105        testing on
11  11:26.0     1105        testing off
12  12:25.6     1105        testing off
13  13:26.0     1105        testing on
14  14:25.6     1106        testing on
15  15:26.0     1105        testing off
16  16:25.6     1105        testing off
17  17:26.0     1105        testing on
18  18:25.7     1105        testing on
19  19:26.0     1105        testing off
20  20:25.7     1105        testing off
21  21:26.1     1105        testing on
22  22:25.7     1106        testing on
23  22:33.7     1107        testing on
24  23:26.1     1105        testing off
25  24:25.7     1105        testing off
26  25:26.1     1105        testing on
27  27:25.7     1105        testing on
28  22:35.7     1106        testing off
```

Now I want to create a new data frame with columns `Id`, `loc_time`, `loc_number`, `status` and `count`.

```
Id  loc_time    loc_number  status          count
1   03:28.5     1105        testing on      03
2   06:25.5     1105        testing         03
3   10:25.6     1105        testing         03
4   13:26.0     1105        testing         03
5   17:26.0     1105        testing         03
6   20:25.7     1105        testing         03
7   24:25.7     1105        testing         03
8   27:25.7     1105        testing off     02
9   22:25.7     1106        testing on      03
10  22:35.7     1106        testing off     01
11  22:33.7     1107        testing on      01
```

I want to group the first ten timestamp records as one record and assign status of test on and also count no of records.

I want to do the same for next ten records and assign status as test.

For the last group of data I want status as test off

How do I do that?

> when 1 - 10 timestamps grouped together for the same loc_number then the status test on.
>
> if there are more than 10 timestamps after the 1- 10 timestamps for the same loc_number then the status is test
>   and so on
>
> if there are less than 10 timestamps after the previous group of 10 timestamps for the same loc_number then the status is test off
>
> the last timestamp grouped together should be test off.

Comment: Just loop the old df with step size 10 and add the values between the steps in a new df like `for i in range(0,len(df),10): df2=pd.DataFrame({"loc_time":np.sum(df["loc_time][i:i+10])})`

Comment: Shouldn't testing be off for the last row of your expected result?

Comment: @Alexander No because it is a new `loc_number`, if new loc number then it should be `testing on`

Comment: @New_learner, you keep changing the data and desired output on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work now.  You can always remove `df2 = df2.set_index('ID')` (the final line) if you don't want to index the dataframe on that column.

First, I needed to sort the dataframe in order by `loc_number` and `loc_time`.

Next, I needed to create continuous blocks of numbers for these unequally sized groups (e.g. 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 assuming two `loc_numbers`).  To do this, I grouped on `loc_number` and performed a transformation that used floor division, using a list comprehension to divide the index of each item by the grouping size (e.g. 3).

`transform(lambda group: [i // group_size for i in range(len(group))]))`

Next, I grouped on the `loc_number` and this new `loc_counter` to do the rest of the aggregations.

I used a list comprehension to get the first and last item of each group.  I then used `.loc` to set the status to `testing_off` or `testing_on`, as appropriate.

```
group_size = 3
df.sort_values(['loc_number', 'loc_time'], inplace=True)
df2 = (
    df
    .assign(
        status='testing',
        loc_counter=df.groupby('loc_number')['loc_number']
                      .transform(lambda group: [i // group_size for i in range(len(group))]))
    .groupby(['loc_number', 'loc_counter'])
    .agg({'loc_time': 'last', 'loc_number': 'last', 'loc_counter': 'count', 'status': 'last'})
    .rename(columns={'loc_counter': 'count'})
    .reset_index(drop=True)   
)

df2['ID'] = range(1, len(df2) + 1)
df2 = df2[['ID', 'loc_time', 'loc_number', 'status', 'count']]

first_group_items = [group[0] for group in df2.groupby('loc_number').groups.itervalues()]
last_group_items = [group[-1] for group in df2.groupby('loc_number').groups.itervalues()]

df2.loc[last_group_items, 'status'] = 'testing_off'
df2.loc[first_group_items, 'status'] = 'testing_on'

df2 = df2.set_index('ID')

>>> df2
   loc_time  loc_number       status  count
ID                                         
1   03:28.5        1105   testing_on      3
2   06:25.5        1105      testing      3
3   10:25.6        1105      testing      3
4   13:26.0        1105      testing      3
5   17:26.0        1105      testing      3
6   20:25.7        1105      testing      3
7   24:25.7        1105      testing      3
8   27:25.7        1105  testing_off      2
9   22:25.7        1106   testing_on      3
10  22:35.7        1106  testing_off      1
11  22:33.7        1107   testing_on      1
```